# Does Human being have potential to perform parthenogenesis?

Tags: genetics, reproduction, asexual-reproduction

Wikipedia says:

> Parthenogenesis can occur without meiosis through mitotic oogenesis. This is called apomictic parthenogenesis. Mature egg cells are produced by mitotic divisions, and these cells directly develop into embryos.
>
> In 1936, Gregory Goodwin Pincus reported successfully inducing *parthenogenesis in a rabbit*. In April 2004, scientists at Tokyo University of Agriculture used *parthenogenesis successfully to create a fatherless mouse*.

Since human is mammal,does not the success of the experimentations hints at the possibility of parthenogenesis in humans,naturally?

If not,why is  parthenogenesis not possible in human beings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Possible' is a tricky word here. There are a lot of things that are possible that just don't happen, because they are so exceedingly rare; or that happen but are unknown because they are hard to spot.

As it happens, we know that parthenogenesis-like effects can be *induced* in humans, because we've done it. If you remember the cloning debacle around [Hwang Woo-suk](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2007/08/03/hwang_parthenogenesis/), it turns out that while he didn't clone anything, he *did* manage to induce parthenogenesis, so … good for him, I guess?

Whether or not it happens in the wild… we just don't know. It's possible that it *does*, but it's really difficult to look for, since women have sex and then subsequently have babies, and a vanishingly small proportion of them are ever DNA tested; so even if one in every one million live births (which is a lot) were the result of parthenogenesis, we might never, ever know.

Basically, it's definitively possible with external meddling; it may or may not be possible without, and it may or may not actually ever happen.